# Display different button/download link on website depending on mobile/desktop OS

Tags: javascript, html

I am wondering if it is possible to display a different button on my site depending on the user's type of operating system (whether it's a **mobile** OS or a **desktop** OS) in Javascript.

More specifically, if the user is running a Windows or Mac system then a 'desktop button' should appear; if the user is on a mobile device a 'mobile button' should appear.

I have not been able to find any guides on how to implement this kind of behaviour although I have seen a similar implementation in use on many other websites.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive) generally to serve me this purpose. All you have to do is to
use the class .visible-phone or .visible-desktop or .hidden-phone.

Accordingly hide the element you want to and show what you want to.

**don't forget to put this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://lessframework.com/ on how to work with @media in css.
Then what you would check for is not the OS or device, but the width of the window in the browser. If it's a desktop, display div a (with button a) and hide any other. If it's a mobile device (smaller screen resolution), then, hide div a, and display div b (with button b).

Example in css:

```
#a {display:block;}
#b {display:none;}
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  #a {display:none;}
  #b {display:block;}
}
```

Note however, that the div a and div b both have a button in them... So if you hide the div, it'll hide the button as well.